# About the nominative on "dimitte nobis debita nostra"

Tags: syntax, ecclesiastical-latin, case

The phrase

> dimitte nobis debita nostra

belongs to the famous prayer Our Father in Latin.
I can understand that *dimitte* is in the active imperative singular form and *nobis* is on dative of "us" as I imagine the verb *dimittere* is bitransitive.
But why is *debita nostra* in the nominative instead of the accusative as it is the object of *dimitte*?

Shouldn't it be *dimitte nobis debitam nostram*?

Comment: Welcome back...!

Comment: well, thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not nominative. It's accusative plural. With neuters, the nominative and the accusative look exactly the same, both ending in -a in the plural.

Also, regarding *nobis*, it's dative of separation with *dimitto*. While the bare dative here is uncommon with this verb in Classical texts (with ab or ex more popular), it's sticking close to the Greek ἡμῖν.

Comment: I read the dative as a *dativus commodi* (dative of advantage) rather than an uncommon substitute for *ex* or *ab*. *Ex* indicates what something is released *from*, but here the dative indicates *for whom* the thing is released.

Comment: (Though I think you're right it's mostly imitating the Greek: the LSJ entry for ἀφίημι specifically lists a legal sense with the dative.)

Comment: @brianpck Oh, yes, advantage makes sense here.

Answer (score 6):

It should indeed be accusative instead of nominative as you say, and it is.
It is the **neuter plural** accusative.

As it does not refer to any specific word appearing earlier but rather general things, the neuter plural is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

**Débita nostra** though seems nominative, is actually accusative... because debita is neuter, and neuters look the same both in nom. and acc.

So, why is **debita**'s ending -a? Because it's a plural, and neuters form the plural in **-a**.

**Debita nostra** is the plural of **debitum nostrum**. So the literal translation would be *forgive us our debts* [or even, *forgive us the things we owe*].

Comment: In fact, one way or another, **all** neuters have a plural ending in *-a* 